# Proving relation between domain and image of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Question:**

$ Let\ \  f:\ A  ->\ B\ and\ C,D\ ⊆\ A.\ $For the following statements, provide a proof if true, otherwise, give a counter example:

1. $ If\ C\ ⊆\ D\ then\ f\left(C\right)⊆\ f\left(D\right) $
2. $ If\ f\left(C\right)⊆\ f\left(D\right)\ then\ C⊆\ D$

I cannot really think of any counter examples to prove both of these statements false. However, I am not sure how to prove that they are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the first one true, you can prove the contrapositive: if $f(C) \not \subseteq f(D)$, then there is some $b \in B$ such that $b \in f(C)$ and $b \not \in f(D)$. So, there is some $c \in C$ such that $f(c)=b$, but there is no $d \in D$ such that $f(d)=b$. But that means that $c \not \in D$, because otherwise we *would* have a $d \in D$ with $f(d)=b$, namely $d =c$. So, $c \in C$ but $c \not \in D$, and therefore $C \not \subseteq D$.

For the second one, any one counterexample is enough to show it is false. So, for example, take $A =\{ a,b,c \}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, and let $f(a)=f(c)=1$ and $f(b)=2$. Finally, let $C=\{ a,c\}$ and $D=\{a,b\}$. Then $f(C)=\{1\}$ and $f(D)=\{1,2\}$, so $f(C) \subseteq f(D)$, but $C \not \subseteq D$

Comment: Can we prove without using contrapositive. Like assume C is a subset of D and then prove that f(C) is a subset of f(D)

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Yes, and in fact that is more straightforward as a proof, but I figured a little less intuitive conceptually, so I went with the contrapositive. But I encourage you to try and do the direct proof! You can add it as an edit when you are done and get some feedback.

Comment: If I assume that C is a subset of D, what else can I say? Could you start me off with a hint?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel now apply the definition of subset: So we get that for every $c \in C$ we have $c \in D$.

Comment: Now, assume $ y \in f(C)$, then $ y \in f(D)$. So, $ y = f(c)\ for\ some\ c \in C\ and\ y = f(d) \ for\ some\ d \in D $. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Almost.  Assume $y \in f(C)$, yes, but from this it does not immediately follow that $y \in f(D)$. So remove that. But then indeed follow up with: since $y \in f(C)$ there must be some $c \in C$ such that $f(c)=y$, but since $C \subseteq D$ we get $c \in D$ ... With still $f(c)=y$, and hence there is some $d \in D$ such that $f(d)=y$ (namely $d=c$). Hence $y \in f(D)$ .   (... So you see, the $y \in f(D)$ comes much later! ...) Anyway, now that we have shown that for any $y \in f(C)$ it holds that $y \in f(D)$, we have shown that $f(C) \subseteq f(D)$. So yeah, you were pretty much there!